# Pushout in Set - Cartesian Product

Tags: category-theory

This is somewhat of a follow up to this question: [Understanding an Example of a *Pushout* in $\mathbf{Set}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240882/understanding-an-example-of-a-pushout-in-mathbfset)

Given the diagram

[image]

the pushout would be the disjoint union under some equivalence relation. My question is: consider the cartesian product $A \times B$. The diagram will not commute since $(x,0) \neq (0,x)$, for $x \in A \cup B$. If I defined a relation on $A \times B$ identifying the pair $(x,0)$ with $(0,x)$ won't that solve the commutativity?

Sorry for grammar mistakes, if any.

Best,
Alex

Comment: What diagram? The one in your picture has no $A\times B$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ and $B$ both contain an element called $0$?

Answer (score 0):

To make things simple, let's assume that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then to formulate your question, we first have to define maps $A, B \to A \times B$, and then ask whether the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\emptyset @>>> B \\
@VVV @VV{u}V \\
A @>{v}>> A \times B
\end{CD}
$$
is a pushout. There are lots of maps $A \to A \times B$, so let's choose one: fix $b_0 \in B$ and use the map $v: a \mapsto (a, b_0)$, and similarly for the other map: $u: b \mapsto (a_0, b)$ for some fixed $a_0 \in A$. (Are these the maps you had in mind?) Then the diagram commutes.

It does not satisfy the universal property of a pushout, though: we also have a commutative diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\emptyset @>>> B \\
@VVV @VV{h}V \\
A @>{k}>> A \amalg B
\end{CD}
$$
where $h$ and $k$ are just the inclusion maps into the disjoint union. If $A \times B$ were the pushout, there would have to be a unique map $t: A \times B \to A \amalg B$ compatible with the maps $A, B \to A \times B$ and the maps $A, B \to A \amalg B$: that is, such that $tu=h$ and $tv=k$. There is no such map $t$, though: where would $(a_0, b_0)$ go? (Consider $t(a_0, b_0) = tu(b_0)$ and $t(a_0, b_0) = tv(a_0)$.)

Comment: "There are lots of maps $A\to A\times B$[.]" Or zero if $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: So maybe I should have said "There are potentially lots of maps ...".